# What is the difference between serverExceptions and Exceptions in Azure signals?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

When defining alerts in Azure, I am able to select a "signal". Two that seem relevant to me are:
Exceptions and Server exceptions. What is the difference between the two? I am failing to find any piece of documentation covering the two.
Where can I see "Server exceptions" occurrences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is very simple:

The [Exceptions (exceptions/count)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/app-insights-metrics#exceptions-exceptionscount) signal contains [Browser exceptions (exceptions/browser)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/app-insights-metrics#browser-exceptions-exceptionsbrowser) and [Server exceptions (exceptions/server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/app-insights-metrics#server-exceptions-exceptionsserver).

You can refer to the links above for more details.